# how can search people by email address in google plus by google api?

Tags: email, search, google-api, google-plus

I want to use **google api** to find people username in google plus by their **email address** , i have ? 
 
 I used follow [this](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) to check people search in google api, but when enter email address , return nothing.
 
 
how can solve this my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses are not searchable on Google+.